# Use jquery to split a string to new line break at certain character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently, the string is

> Package A (123 queries) Package B (212 queries)

Is it possible to use jquery to split it into new line like

> - Package A (123 queries)
> - Package B (212 queries)

I was thinking to insert line break after each closing bracket. But not sure if it is appropriate.

---

**Edit 1**

**In HTML**

```
<ul class="list">
    <li><span id="requested-package">@Model[0].regDescription[a]</span></li>
    <li>Testing</li>
</ul>
```

**Output**  - I want to make the Plan A in next line
[image]

---

**Edit 2**

```
    var str = $('.hidden-package').text();
    var line = str.replace(')', ') <br>');
    $('.requested-package').html(line);
```

Current Output

[image]
I created a hidden field `hidden-package`and from there I managed to get the text value using `.text()`. 
The problem now is it only replaces the first occurrence of closing bracket. How can I replace all the closing bracket with `<br>`. Thanks.

**Solution**

Managed to solve this by changing the code above to the below.

```
    var str = $('.hidden-package').text();
    var line = str.replace(/\)/g, ')<br>');
    $('.requested-package').html(line);
```

Comment: If it's just a "string", then no - use javascript, not jquery - jquery is for DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.replace` but try to be as specific as possible. Here we look for where you have a closing bracket followed by a space followed by 'Package' followed by another space `') Package '`. This should help prevent erroneous results

```
'Package A (123 queries) Package B (212 queries)'.replace(') Package ', ')\nPackage')
```

Comment: Hi Shaun. Thank you for the solution. I managed to replace it with a new line but I used `<br>` instead. However, it only replaces the first occurrence of `)`. Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

```
'Package A (123 queries) Package B (212 queries)'.replace(') ', ')\n')
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I managed to replace it with a new line but I used `<br>` instead. However, it only replaces the first occurrence of `)`. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: You can give me the whole string and the ideal result.

Comment: I have edited my post above mentioned in **Edit 2** :) thanks

Comment: great flag 'g' can replace all matched content :D

Answer (score 1):

Add any special character where you want to split the string and replace it with a line break, this should add a new line in html.

For example

```
var string = "Package A (123 queries)~Package B (212 queries)~Package C (212 queries)";
string = string .replace(/~/g, "<br />");
```

Comment: I have edited my post above, I'm now facing problems to replace every occurrences of `)` instead of only the first one. Any idea how to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to convert contents of the variable `someStr` to ***string*** using `toString()` function:

So if my string looks like this:

`someStr = 'Package A (123 queries)~ Package B (212 queries)'` with the special character "~" inserted (as suggested by **@user2703788**), convert the variable `someStr` as:

`someStr = someStr.toString();` And then `replace`

So we may use:

`someStr = someStr.toString().replace(/~/g, "<br />");`

And display the contents:

$('#myMessage').html(someStr);